# Multiple Security Dialogs While Executing Single Java Application through Web Start

Tags: java, security, digital-signature

My company has a Java application that we recently started signing with a Godaddy certificate. This is an application that is deployed through Web Start. I've been testing it on jdk 7u45. As expected, I get a security dialog box asking me to install the certificate for the publisher (my company). This is fine, but then it's followed by two more security dialogs warning me that I'm executing an application by an unknown publisher. So this is really a two part question:

1. Why are there multiple dialogs for the same application?
2. Why are two of them reporting the publisher as unknown?

I'm not sure what additional information would be useful for diagnosing this problem, but I can provide more if it would be helpful.

Edit: I use Maven to build the application, which automates the code signing. There may be something going wrong with Maven's default signing procedure, but I'm not sure what that would be.

Update: After running Jcs's command, and checking the Maven log, it looks like everything is signed and in the manifest as far as I can tell. Every file is reporting smk except the manifest (which is sk, obviously).

Update: I did find this in the Maven log in a few dependencies:

```
[debug] Executing: /bin/sh -c "cd /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/jaguar/jaguar-core/target/jnlp && /var/lib/jenkins/tools/hudson.model.JDK/jdk7u25/jre/../bin/jarsigner -verify /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/jaguar/jaguar-core/target/jnlp/lib/unprocessed_equinox-common-3.6.0.jar"
[info] jar verified.
[info] 
[info] Warning: 
[info] This jar contains entries whose signer certificate has expired. 
[info] This jar contains entries whose certificate chain is not validated.
[info] 
[info] Re-run with the -verbose and -certs options for more details.
[INFO] remove signature from : /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/jaguar/jaguar-core/target/jnlp/lib/unprocessed_equinox-common-3.6.0.jar
[info] remove file :/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/jaguar/jaguar-core/target/jnlp/lib/temp_extracted_jars/unprocessed_equinox-common-3.6.0.jar/META-INF/ECLIPSEF.SF
[info] remove file :/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/jaguar/jaguar-core/target/jnlp/lib/temp_extracted_jars/unprocessed_equinox-common-3.6.0.jar/META-INF/ECLIPSEF.RSA
[INFO] Building jar: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/jaguar/jaguar-core/target/jnlp/lib/unprocessed_equinox-common-3.6.0.jar
```

I don't know what "unprocessed" means, but the same jar "equinox-common", without the "unprocessed" in the title appears later in the build to be signed properly:

```
../bin/jarsigner -verify -verbose /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/jaguar/jaguar-core/target/jnlp/lib/equinox-common-3.6.0.jar"
[info] 
[info] s       7814 Tue Dec 10 10:42:46 CST 2013 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
[info]         7940 Tue Dec 10 10:42:46 CST 2013 META-INF/JAG_CERT.SF
[info]         4247 Tue Dec 10 10:42:46 CST 2013 META-INF/JAG_CERT.RSA
[info]            0 Tue Dec 10 10:40:28 CST 2013 META-INF/
[info] sm        76 Thu Jun 24 08:53:50 CDT 2010 META-INF/eclipse.inf
[info] sm      1746 Thu Jun 24 08:34:48 CDT 2010 org/eclipse/core/runtime/SubMonitor$RootInfo.class
[info] sm       301 Thu Jun 24 08:34:46 CDT 2010 org/eclipse/core/runtime/IProgressMonitorWithBlocking.class
[info] sm      6213 Thu Jun 24 08:34:46 CDT 2010 org/eclipse/core/runtime/PluginVersionIdentifier.class
[info] sm      1582 Thu Jun 24 08:34:46 CDT 2010 org/eclipse/core/runtime/CoreException.class
[info] sm      3918 Thu Jun 24 08:34:46 CDT 2010 org/eclipse/core/runtime/Status.class
[info] sm       187 Thu Jun 24 08:34:46 CDT 2010 org/eclipse/core/runtime/IAdaptable.class
[info] sm      1194 Thu Jun 24 08:34:46 CDT 2010 org/eclipse/core/runtime/NullProgressMonitor.class
[info] sm      2110 Thu Jun 24 08:34:46 CDT 2010 org/eclipse/core/runtime/ProgressMonitorWrapper.class
[info] sm       384 Thu Jun 24 08:34:46 CDT 2010 org/eclipse/core/runtime/IBundleGroup.class
[info] sm      2499 Thu Jun 24 08:34:46 CDT 2010 org/eclipse/core/runtime/SafeRunner.class
[info] sm      1560 Thu Jun 24 08:34:46 CDT 2010 org/eclipse/core/runtime/QualifiedName.class
[info] sm      4912 Thu Jun 24 08:34:48 CDT 2010 org/eclipse/core/runtime/SubMonitor.class
[info] sm      2646 Thu Jun 24 08:34:46 CDT 2010 org/eclipse/core/runtime/MultiStatus.class
[info] sm       253 Thu Jun 24 08:34:46 CDT 2010 org/eclipse/core/runtime/ISafeRunnable.class
[info] sm       237 Thu Jun 24 08:34:46 CDT 2010 org/eclipse/core/runtime/ILogListener.class
[info] sm      1896 Thu Jun 24 08:34:46 CDT 2010 org/eclipse/core/runtime/ListenerList.class
[info] sm       575 Thu Jun 24 08:34:46 CDT 2010 org/eclipse/core/runtime/IStatus.class
[info] sm       722 Thu Jun 24 08:34:46 CDT 2010 org/eclipse/core/runtime/PlatformObject.class
[info] sm       258 Thu Jun 24 08:34:46 CDT 2010 org/eclipse/core/runtime/IBundleGroupProvider.class
[info] sm       572 Thu Jun 24 08:34:46 CDT 2010 org/eclipse/core/runtime/OperationCanceledException.class
[info] sm       860 Thu Jun 24 08:34:46 CDT 2010 org/eclipse/core/runtime/IAdapterManager.class
[info] sm      2725 Thu Jun 24 08:34:46 CDT 2010 org/eclipse/core/runtime/FileLocator.class
[info] sm       263 Thu Jun 24 08:34:46 CDT 2010 org/eclipse/core/runtime/IAdapterFactory.class
[info] sm      6756 Thu Jun 24 08:34:48 CDT 2010 org/eclipse/core/runtime/URIUtil.class
[info] sm       431 Thu Jun 24 08:34:46 CDT 2010 org/eclipse/core/runtime/IProgressMonitor.class
[info] sm       484 Thu Jun 24 08:34:46 CDT 2010 org/eclipse/core/runtime/AssertionFailedException.class
[info] sm      1508 Thu Jun 24 08:34:46 CDT 2010 org/eclipse/core/runtime/IPath.class
[info] sm      1350 Thu Jun 24 08:34:46 CDT 2010 org/eclipse/core/runtime/Assert.class
[info] sm      2431 Thu Jun 24 08:34:48 CDT 2010 org/eclipse/core/runtime/SubProgressMonitor.class
[info] sm     14651 Thu Jun 24 08:34:46 CDT 2010 org/eclipse/core/runtime/Path.class
[info] sm      3255 Thu Jun 24 08:34:46 CDT 2010 org/eclipse/core/internal/boot/PlatformURLHandler.class
[info] sm      2092 Thu Jun 24 08:34:46 CDT 2010 org/eclipse/core/internal/boot/PlatformURLBaseConnection.class
[info] sm     11789 Thu Jun 24 08:34:46 CDT 2010 org/eclipse/core/internal/boot/PlatformURLConnection.class
[info] sm      1293 Thu Jun 24 08:34:46 CDT 2010 org/eclipse/core/internal/runtime/PlatformURLConverter.class
[info] sm      7591 Thu Jun 24 08:34:46 CDT 2010 org/eclipse/core/internal/runtime/FindSupport.class
[info] sm      3034 Thu Jun 24 08:34:48 CDT 2010 org/eclipse/core/internal/runtime/commonMessages.properties
[info] sm      2951 Thu Jun 24 08:34:46 CDT 2010 org/eclipse/core/internal/runtime/PlatformURLFragmentConnection.class
[info] sm      2705 Thu Jun 24 08:34:46 CDT 2010 org/eclipse/core/internal/runtime/DevClassPathHelper.class
[info] sm       675 Thu Jun 24 08:34:46 CDT 2010 org/eclipse/core/internal/runtime/MetaDataKeeper.class
[info] sm      1717 Thu Jun 24 08:34:46 CDT 2010 org/eclipse/core/internal/runtime/PrintStackUtil.class
[info] sm      1423 Thu Jun 24 08:34:46 CDT 2010 org/eclipse/core/internal/runtime/LocalizationUtils.class
[info] sm      5419 Thu Jun 24 08:34:46 CDT 2010 org/eclipse/core/internal/runtime/ResourceTranslator.class
[info] sm      9033 Thu Jun 24 08:34:46 CDT 2010 org/eclipse/core/internal/runtime/AdapterManager.class
[info] sm      1951 Thu Jun 24 08:34:46 CDT 2010 org/eclipse/core/internal/runtime/CommonMessages.class
[info] sm      1218 Thu Jun 24 08:34:46 CDT 2010 org/eclipse/core/internal/runtime/ReferenceHashSet$StrongReference.class
[info] sm       390 Thu Jun 24 08:34:46 CDT 2010 org/eclipse/core/internal/runtime/IRuntimeConstants.class
[info] sm      3672 Thu Jun 24 08:34:46 CDT 2010 org/eclipse/core/internal/runtime/PlatformURLMetaConnection.class
[info] sm      5094 Thu Jun 24 08:34:46 CDT 2010 org/eclipse/core/internal/runtime/ReferenceHashSet.class
[info] sm      2741 Thu Jun 24 08:34:46 CDT 2010 org/eclipse/core/internal/runtime/RuntimeLog.class
[info] sm     10406 Thu Jun 24 08:34:46 CDT 2010 org/eclipse/core/internal/runtime/Activator.class
[info] sm      1895 Thu Jun 24 08:34:46 CDT 2010 org/eclipse/core/internal/runtime/ReferenceHashSet$HashableSoftReference.class
[info] sm       240 Thu Jun 24 08:34:46 CDT 2010 org/eclipse/core/internal/runtime/IAdapterManagerProvider.class
[info] sm      1785 Thu Jun 24 08:34:46 CDT 2010 org/eclipse/core/internal/runtime/ReferenceHashSet$HashableWeakReference.class
[info] sm      4032 Thu Jun 24 08:34:46 CDT 2010 org/eclipse/core/internal/runtime/PlatformURLPluginConnection.class
[info] sm       271 Thu Jun 24 08:34:46 CDT 2010 org/eclipse/core/internal/runtime/IAdapterFactoryExt.class
[info] sm      6107 Thu Jun 24 08:34:46 CDT 2010 org/eclipse/core/internal/runtime/DataArea.class
[info] sm      3649 Thu Jun 24 08:34:46 CDT 2010 org/eclipse/core/internal/runtime/PlatformURLConfigConnection.class
[info] sm       330 Thu Jun 24 08:34:46 CDT 2010 org/eclipse/core/internal/runtime/ReferenceHashSet$HashedReference.class
[info] sm       780 Thu Jun 24 08:34:48 CDT 2010 org/eclipse/equinox/events/MemoryEventConstants.class
[info] sm       604 Wed May 20 16:19:18 CDT 2009 plugin.properties
[info] sm       641 Thu Jun 24 08:39:44 CDT 2010 .api_description
[info] sm      1432 Sat Jun 03 09:14:58 CDT 2006 about.html
[info]            0 Thu Jun 24 08:34:46 CDT 2010 org/
[info]            0 Thu Jun 24 08:34:46 CDT 2010 org/eclipse/
[info]            0 Thu Jun 24 08:34:46 CDT 2010 org/eclipse/core/
[info]            0 Tue Dec 10 10:40:28 CST 2013 org/eclipse/core/runtime/
[info]            0 Tue Dec 10 10:40:28 CST 2013 org/eclipse/core/internal/
[info]            0 Tue Dec 10 10:40:28 CST 2013 org/eclipse/core/internal/boot/
[info]            0 Tue Dec 10 10:40:28 CST 2013 org/eclipse/core/internal/runtime/
[info]            0 Thu Jun 24 08:34:48 CDT 2010 org/eclipse/equinox/
[info]            0 Thu Jun 24 08:34:48 CDT 2010 org/eclipse/equinox/events/
[info] 
[info]   s = signature was verified 
[info]   m = entry is listed in manifest
[info]   k = at least one certificate was found in keystore
[info]   i = at least one certificate was found in identity scope
[info] 
[info] jar verified.
```

Comment: *"executing an application by an unknown publisher"*  It seems the code is not properly signed, according to the JRE.  Be sure to uninstall the previous apps. before testing with a new version.

Comment: Well, the application is built using Maven. I would think that all of the necessary signing should take place. Can you think of a reason why it might not? I'm sure there are elements of the Maven build process that I'm not aware of. Like I mentioned, though, the first dialog indicates that the code has been signed and verified.

Comment: *"I'm sure there are elements of the Maven build process that I'm not aware of."*  I don't use Maven, so don't ask me.

Comment: You can verify the signature of the jar with this command: jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs -keystore myKeystore.jks application.jar

Comment: Thanks. I think that is the same data that is displayed in the Maven build log, but I ran your command just to be sure, and it looks like everything is signed and in the manifest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer turns out to be simpler than I expected. We deploy our application through Web Start (jnlp). The main jnlp references other jnlps that include external libraries that are not managed by our build system, thus were not signed with a verified certificate. I wasn't aware of these dependencies, since I wasn't the person who initially created the application. There were two dependencies, each causing a separate security dialog.

**In summary**: The cause of this problem is external dependencies, signed by an unverified certificate, that are not managed by the maven build process, but are referenced through unique jnlps.